# Google Wave like WYSIWYG

Tags: wysiwyg, google-wave

I was searching for the google wave-like wysiwyg editor but did not succeed on it. I've tried jWYSIWYG, clEditor and couple of other editors.

Now i want to implement it by myself. Do you have any ideas about how it working? Especially how do they draw a caret and handle mouse/keyboard events and text selection.

I don't want to use any existing WYSIWYG editors because they dont give me what i want.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have no idea where to start, this is going to be a very difficult task. You should really try to find an editor that you can modify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question -- use **contentEditable** property.

Answer (score 0):

You could peek at the source code of some of the popular open source editors to get an idea of their approach, might give you some insight into how you want to tackle your solution.

TinyMCE is on GitHub:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce

CKEditor has a SVN repo:

http://dev.ckeditor.com/browser

And of course, they are Javascript, so you really look at any of them you want to.

Comment: They are all using iFrame and replace <textarea> with it. That's the first reason why i dont want to use this kind of editors.